# Number of trials to observe all values of a uniform discrete random variable X with a probability of at least 1-q?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let X take on p values with equal probability. If n trials are to be conducted to ensure that the probability of not observing any of these p values is less than or equal to q, what is the value of n?

Here's what I've been able to do so far -
Let $ X $ take on values $ 1, 2, ... p $. Let $ X_i $ denote the event that the value $ i $ is observed in the $ n $ trials. Then, we want

$ Pr(X_1^C \cup X_2^C \cup ... X_p^C) \leq q $

$ X_1^C \cup X_2^C \cup ... X_p^C = (X_1 X_2 ... X_p)^ C $, so we need $ Pr(X_1 X_2 ... X_p) \geq 1 - q $.

And one lower bound for this probability is

$ Pr(X_1 X_2 ... X_p) > \frac{{n-1 \choose p-1}}{p^n} $. Using this,

$ \frac{{n-1 \choose p-1}}{p^n} > 1 - q $

Not sure how to obtain the value of n from here. Are there other bounds/methods which make the calculation for $ n $ more conducive?

Comment: There are no tricks. If you want to get the exact minimal value of $n$, it is the minimal value satisfying the inequality. That's a closed form answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the inclusion-exclusion formula to calculate the probability that you are not seeing all values after a given number of trials. Then you can answer your own question. You won't get a nice formula but that's the best you can do if you want the exact number of trials. (You can get asymptotic results but that's probably premature at your stage.)

For fixed $q$ and as $p\to\infty$ (or for fixed $p$ and $q \to 0$), we know that $n\gg p$ and so $\binom{n-1}{p-1} \approx n^{p-1}/(p-1)!$, from which we find that the critical $n$ is the solution to $n^{p-1}/p^n = (1-q)(p-1)!$. Taking the logarithm, we find $(p-1)\log n - n\log p = \log[(1-q)(p-1)!]$, from which we can estimate $n \approx -\log[(1-q)(p-1)!]/\log p$ and then obtain the better estimate $(p-1)\log\{-\log[(1-q)(p-1)!]/\log p\} -n\log p = \log[(1-q)(p-1)!]$, from which you can get an approximate formula for $n$. If you're very careful then you can probably prove an honest-to-god asymptotic estimate.

Comment: Added my approach to the body of the question. Any suggestions on how to proceed from here/alternate bounds for the probability?